# Make use of a java object in Perl

Tags: java, perl, selenium-webdriver

Scenario :

there is a java class as given below :

```
public class TestSelenium {
    public void googleTest() throws Exception {     
       WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
       driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");
    }
}
```

There is a perl program which makes use of Inline::Java module to call the googleTest of java class written above. Perl program looks like.

```
use warnings;
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

use Inline Java => 'STUDY',

CLASSPATH => 'C:\selenium\selenium-java-2.37.0\selenium-2.37.0\libs\selenium-java-2.37.0.jar;C:\selenium\SeleniumTestPoc\bin\MyJar.jar;C:\selenium\selenium-java-2.37.0\selenium-2.37.0\libs\selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar',

STUDY => ['TestSelenium'];

$test= TestSelenium->new;

$test->googleTest;
```

Now the above Perl code will open IExplorer and go to google.com page. In my Perl program further to $test->googleTest; I want to make use of same browser that was opened by java(WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();) and perform a search for text "Cheese".

**Question** is, can the object of WebDriver class("driver" in this case) be further used in my Perl program so that I can use same browser and perform different UI operations on it in Perl?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that if you bring the `WebDriver` variable outside of the `googleTest()` method (making it available for all methods in the class) then you can write other methods in `TestSelenium` that reference the same `WebDriver` which you can then call in perl.

Modify `TestSelenium` to something like this:

```
public class TestSelenium {
    private WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    public void googleTest() throws Exception {     
       driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");
    }

    public void searchForCheese() throws Exception {
       // Your actions here can still reference the driver
    }
}
```

And then after you call `$test= TestSelenium->new;`

Performing `$test->googleTest;` and `$test->searchForCheese;` should theoretically reference the same driver and in turn the same browser window.

**EDIT :**

If you want to pass the `driver` object back to perl try something like this.

Change the `googleTest()` java method to return the driver once it's done with the method (I will be using your original method but both should work):

```
public WebDriver googleTest() throws Exception {     
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");
   return driver;
}
```

And then I think you can hook onto the driver handle in perl via `$mydriver= $test->goggleTest;`

I assume you'll then be able to access the `WebDriver` hooks via `$mydriver`

Comment: Hi Ceiling Gecko,

Thanks for looking into this.
 java object("driver") will open browser and will go to google.com page and then, can same object("driver") be used in perl so that it perform operations 
 further on browser that are part of function searchForCheese() mentioned by you. In other words, is there any way by which handle of browser can switch from java to perl?

Comment: @user1474594 Edited in some additional things you might try. Changes to your original `googleTest()` method involve changing the return type from `void` to `WebDriver` and adding a line at the end of the method `return driver;` to return the "driver" object.